# Jquery Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to create an autocomplete search field from a json file with Jquery Typeahead, to have an autocomplete preview on search inputs similar to google search, based on this example: http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/ (Beer v1).

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
        <span class="typeahead__query">
            <input class="js-typeahead-input"
                   name="q"
                   type="search"
                   autofocus
                   autocomplete="off">
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var data = {
    countries: ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"],
    capitals: ["Abu Dhabi", "Abuja", "Accra"]
};
typeof $.typeahead === 'function' && $.typeahead({
    input: ".js-typeahead-input",
    minLength: 1,
    order: "asc",
    group: true,
    maxItemPerGroup: 5,
    groupOrder: function () {
        var scope = this,
            sortGroup = [];
        for (var i in this.result) {
            sortGroup.push({
                group: i,
                length: this.result[i].length
            });
        }
        sortGroup.sort(
            scope.helper.sort(
                ["length"],
                true, // false = desc, the most results on top
                function (a) {
                    return a.toString().toUpperCase()
                }
            )
        );
        return $.map(sortGroup, function (val, i) {
            return val.group
        });
    },
    hint: true,
    dropdownFilter: "All",
    template: "{{display}}, <small><em>{{group}}</em></small>",
    emptyTemplate: "nothing for : {{query}}",
    source: {
        country: {
            data: data.countries
        },
        capital: {
            data: data.capitals
        }
    },
    debug: true
});
```

I tried to replace actual source by

```
    source: {
        "coutries": {
            ajax: {
                url: "coutries.json",
                path: "data"
            }
        },
        "capitals": {
            ajax: {
                url: "capitals.json",
                path: "data"
            }
        },
}
```

The problem is that I can't add the JSON files to load results from.

Final result should look like this :
[image]

Comment: Please explain what does not work : give us the error, or the result you have !

Comment: The problem is that i can't add the json files to load results from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax - GET method to get the data from database or from elsewhere you want. 
Refer following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "your ajax url",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
            typeof $.typeahead === 'function' && $.typeahead({
                input: ".js-typeahead-input",
                minLength: 1, //minimum character length
                order: "asc",
                hint: true,
                source: data,
                debug: true
          });
       }
});
```